# Почему переменная undefined в функции?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в переменная a в функции makeDiv получает undefined?

```js
        var a=10000;
    (function makeDiv(a){
      var b=a+1000;
        var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
        var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
        $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
            'width':'50px',
            'height':'50px',
            'background-color': color
        });
    
        var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
        var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();
    
        $newdiv.css({
            'position':'absolute',
            'left':posx+'px',
            'top':posy+'px',
            'display':'none'
        }).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut(200, function(){
           $(this).remove();
           makeDiv();
        });
        console.log(a);
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внутри функции у Вас переменная `а` - это параметр, который Вы не подаете в вызов функции.

```js
var a = 10000;
(function makeDiv(/* do not redefine "a" by declaring parameter of the same name */) {
  var b = a + 1000;
  console.log(a, b);
})();
```

или

```js
var a = 10000;
(function makeDiv(a) {
  var b = a + 1000;
  console.log(a, b);
})(a /* pass global "a" as parameter "a" - they may have different names */);
```

Comment: Все дело в невнимательности оказалось... Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @slake, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)